# How to get variable with directory path in python script from bash script?

Tags: python, bash

I would like to know how can i get current working directory as parameter in python script, my bash script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
working_derictory=($PWD) #set working directory to variable
eval "python3.8 main.py" working_directory
```

in python script i try to get this variable using:

```
import sys
print (sys.argv[1])
```

after execution i get `working_directory` text instead of directory path 
also i tried to change it `eval "python3.8 main.py" working_directory` to `eval "python3.8 main.py" pwd` but i got the same result.
Please point me what i did wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options.

```
working_directory=$PWD
python3.8 main.py "$working_directory"
```

This will pass the value of your variable as a command line argument.  In  Python you will use `sys.argv[1]` to access it.

```
export working_directory=$PWD
python3.8 main.py
```

This will add an environment variable using `export`.  In Python you can access this using `import os` and `os.getenv('working_directory')`.

You also can use this syntax:

```
working_directory=$PWD python3.8 main.py
```

This results in the same (an environment variable) without cluttering the environment of the calling shell.

Comment: Oh i just missed $ sing before working_directory, thank you for informative answer with different implementation variants !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pathlib` library to avoid putting it as a parameter:

```
import pathlib

working_derictory = pathlib.Path().absolute()
```

Comment: Thank you but, i will check it!